# Batch send email forward requests using Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I was encountering request throttling when forwarding emails one at a time in a loop using the Microsoft Graph SDK, so I've opted to use the *batch requests* feature (described with examples by the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp)).

I have tried posting a batch with a single message forward request but it's not working — I'm not sure what's wrong.

If it's of any help, the `status` of the `Task<BatchResponseContent>` returned by the call to the batch's `postAsync()` is `WaitingForActivation`.

#### Non-batched single request — working

Calling this for any email message works, although when calling it repeatedly in a loop some message forward requests get ignored due to throttling.

```
public async void ForwardMessage(mailbox, messageID, toRecipients, forwardComment)
{
        await _graphServiceClient
            .Users[mailbox]
            .Messages[messageID.ToString()]
            .Forward(toRecipients, null, forwardComment)
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();
}
```

#### Batched single request — not working

Wrapping the same single request from before in a `BatchRequestContent` and then posting the batch isn't working.

```
public async void ForwardMessage(mailbox, messageID, toRecipients, forwardComment)
{

        var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

        var request = _graphServiceClient
            .Users[mailbox]
            .Messages[messageID.ToString()]
            .Forward(toRecipients, null, forwardComment)
            .Request();

        batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(request);

        await _graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the whole response of Batch request?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity How do I access the whole response? Which member?

Comment: Please share the requestid, timestamp so that we can have a look at.

Comment: @Dev Here's one: `ddaf3888-dfad-47a3-ae51-39d3f573daaa` 14:49

Comment: timestamp also for the requestid too

Comment: @micycle Were you ever able to get a solution on this? I'm having a similar issue (I'm doing `SendMail` instead of forward). Emails are not sent via batches even though code runs without exceptions or errors.

Comment: @thankyoussd I was never able to get batch requests working. Instead I had to sent multiple single requests, adding a wait of ~0.1s between each one to prevent request throttling.

Comment: Microsoft Graph SDK defaults to HTTP GET requests. But for Forward you have to use HTTP POST. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71655449/20786 for an example.